# Serializing data into a single text field - denormalization gone too far?

Tags: database, database-design, denormalization

I'd love some opinions on whether this database design I'm currently pursuing is sound or not.

Lets assume I'm building a table called "Home", this table has a text field called "rooms". In this field is the serialized data for a set of rooms that this house has. My first instinct was to, of course, normalize this data into a separate "Rooms" table. However, due to some frustrating experiences with overly normalized databases in the past, I stopped to ask myself a few questions:

1. Will I ever need to find a specific room?
2. Will I ever need to update an individual room?
3. Will any Home records ever share Room records?

The answer to each of these questions is "no". Room records are all unique to each Home. Queries will never need to be performed to find out how many Homes in the database have bathrooms, for instance. Data will always be pulled from the perspective of the Home. The number of bedrooms and bathrooms will be explicitly stored on the Home record for searching.

So instead of having to constantly join Rooms, I wondered what would be the harm in serializing this data and just popping it into a text field.

This makes a lot of sense to me, but I'm hoping for a sanity check. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Stringly typed data representation just doesn't sound right, no matter that YSAGNI (like YAGNI, only with "supposedly" ;)).

Comment: Will you ever need to search for homes with at least 3 bedrooms?

Comment: what data do you hold about each room? It almost sounds like you are treating the room data as a "binary payload" for some other application rather than work with in in your own. If that's not the case, I wonder if you need to store the room data at all?

Comment: @Martin - yes, but I'm explicitly storing the number of bedrooms and bathrooms on the Home record

Comment: @Ronnis - it's typical real estate stuff. Basic dimensions, name of the room, type of room. This data is only ever displayed on a page for a Home. It's essentially just structured metadata for the Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what others have said about doing the right thing, I would like to add a comment about performance.

Since you will be storing the serialized room data as a column in table Home, the row size will increase significantly. This will result in **worse performance for all other queries**.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for. Since my main motivation (outside of simplifying my application logic), was to increase performance (simple select vs joins seemed better at first glance).

Do you have any further information or resources that explain the performance implications of row size? I'm using MySQL if that matters.

Also when you say "all other queries" do you mean all other queries pertaining to Home, or queries database wide?

Comment: @jmking, mainly those referencing Home. Table scans will take longer because the table consumes more disk space. Indexes access will be less efficient since a smaller percentage of the table will fit into the cache. In theory, that last point will also impact unrelated queries since the cache will have room for less data for other tables.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you might not have a need TODAY to query to find out things like:

- What is the average number of bathrooms in a home in Ohio?
- Where do homes have more bedrooms?  The East Coast or the West Coast?
- How does house price correlate with the size of the master bedroom?  What would be the average dollar value return of increasing the master bedroom size by 30%?

etc, etc.

You will be in a much better position in the future if you design your foundation correctly to begin with... no matter how enticing the short-cut may seem right now.

Plus, with a separate ROOMS table, you will be able to add additional room fields that make sense later (like width/height, color, floor level, etc.) which would all be very hard if the data were just globbed into a single field.

People will want to query in unexpected ways, like:

- I have bad knees.  Can you list houses with the master bedroom and master bathroom on the first floor?

In general, having a ROOMS table will just make your application more powerful, and easier to use.

Hey, I get what you're saying about "overly normalized data".  We've all been there, and it DOES bite.  However, having a ROOMS table in a database with housing info isn't being "overly normalized".  It's just building the app the right way.

Comment: This is definitely a consideration. However, I figured it we ever wanted to pull that meaning out, I could always grab a snapshot of the database and write a small script to peel it back out into another table. If we ever were to do high level reporting, this would be handled by a separate application and would never hit the live database anyway.

Comment: Well, grabbing a data snapshot and writing a script just to query if the master bedroom is on the first floor is a LOT more work than just designing the application correctly to begin with, but it sounds like you may have already made up your mind.  Look at the other comments on this page, and see what the community thinks...

Comment: Haven't made up my mind by any stretch, just trying to figure out if there's a performance reason not to do this. When you say "designing the application correctly", I'm trying to figure out what ISN'T technically correct about this approach given the requirements. eg - would adding a text field to a table with millions of records be worse off than a join?

Comment: Hi jmking - Sure, there would be a performance reason to keep the data separate.  In addition to what @Ronnis wrote above, there wouldn't be a way to get just the room info you're looking for.  You'd have to get it all... or get nothing.  You also couldn't index the frequently accessed room information, and if you have millions of rows... that's a whole lot of unnecessary globbed data to retrieve on each query (unless it all IS necessary, of course).  So, there is definitely a performance impact to denormalizing a database (and its usually [but not always] negative).

Answer (score 3):

A pragmatic answer...

- a) probability that you might want to decompose it in the future
- b) benefit of not doing so now
- c) cost of changing the schema later on.

If `a * c > b` then you should decompose now.

Comment: It made me think of [technical debt](http://forums.construx.com/blogs/stevemcc/archive/2007/11/01/technical-debt-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you say that room records are unique, but you can't enforce that. So you have no way to know this for sure in your current design: all your code should be perfect in representing this.

"constantly joining" isn't that hard to do, but if it is, you can always make a View for that, and you're done.

Comment: They are unique as in they are unique to the home. Even if they were pulled out into a separate table, I couldn't stop someone from entering the same room twice.

Comment: I presume that a unique room is a room with a unique function (you can add functions-types to a room table) or a unique name. You could serialize 2 "bathroom" rooms into a home, but you could not add 2 "bathroom" rows to a table with a unique home-roomIdentifier key.

Comment: Also, looking at @martin 's answer: I'd say that the benefit of not normalizing is zero....